# Standard emailer class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going through my app, trying to clean up some code that sends e-mails. I started creating my own emailer wrapper class, but then I figured that there must be a standard emailer class out there somewhere. I've done some searching, but couldn't find anything.

Also, is there a code base for stuff like this anywhere?

**EDIT**: Sorry, let me clarify.

I don't want to have this in my code any time I need to send an e-mail:

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
message.From="from e-mail";
message.To="to e-mail";
message.Subject="Message Subject";
message.Body="Message Body";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer="SMTP Server Address";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

I created a class named Emailer, that contains functions like:

```
SendEmail(string to, string from, string body)
SendEmail(string to, string from, string body, bool isHtml)
```

And so I can just put this a single line in my code to send an e-mail:

```
Emailer.SendEmail("name@site.com", "name2@site.com", "My e-mail", false);
```

I mean, it's not too complex, but I figured there was a standard, accepted solution out there.

Comment: Please clarify.  What do you mean by "standard emailer class"?  Something that turns form fields into an email?

Comment: @anon, agreed.  I assume the OP is not simply asking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx ?

Comment: @Kirk Woll Actually, I get the impression that he is.

Comment: I think he wants to have a service layer for sending emails.

Comment: @Shawn - Yes, that is what I mean. :) Apologies for the confusion, I'm terrible at putting what I need into words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using MailMessage=System.Net.Mail.MailMessage;

class CTEmailSender
{
    string MailSmtpHost { get; set; }
    int MailSmtpPort { get; set; }
    string MailSmtpUsername { get; set; }
    string MailSmtpPassword { get; set; }
    string MailFrom { get; set; }

    public bool SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(MailFrom, to, subject, body);
        var alternameView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, new ContentType("text/html"));
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(alternameView);

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(MailSmtpHost, MailSmtpPort);
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MailSmtpUsername, MailSmtpPassword);
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log error here
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is there a code base where you got this from, or do you know of a code base that has code services like this?

Comment: @Steven: I just took a class out of my project code:) 70-536 training book has a good chapter about sending e-mails.

Comment: Could be sounds like a newbie question. What does the statement "using MailMessage=System.Net.Mail.MailMessage;" mean? Your code should work without it since you have already imported System.Net.Mail.

Comment: @Jonas Everest: I have to admit, it is not needed here any more. This construction is used when you have two classes called `MailMessage` in two or more different namespaces and you want to point, that `MailMessage` in this file points to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage. I believe .NET had `MailMessage`class in different namespace, but it was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I use a generic class made out of [this old Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/32336#32336).
Try this.

---

```
public bool SendEmail(MailAddress toAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("pull from db or web.config", "pull from db or web.config");
    string fromPassword = "pull from db or config and decrypt";
    string smtpHost = "pull from db or web.config";
    int smtpPort = 587;//gmail port

    try
    {
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = smtpHost,
            Port = smtpPort,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(err);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from one of my projects.  It's a little more feature-packed than some of the other implementations.

Using this function allows you to create an email with:

- Tokens that can be replaced with actual values at runtime
- Emails that contain both a text and HTML view

  ```
  public MailMessage createMailMessage(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string subject, string template)
  {
  // Validate arguments here...

  // If your template contains any of the following {tokens}
  // they will be replaced with the values you set here.
  var replacementDictionary = new ListDictionary
         {
             // Replace with your own list of values
             { "{first}", "Pull from db or config" },
             { "{last}", "Pull from db or config" }
         };

  // Create a text view and HTML view (both will be in the same email)
  // This snippet assumes you are using ASP.NET (works w/MVC)
  //    if not, replace HostingEnvironment.MapPath with your own path.
  var mailDefinition = new MailDefinition { BodyFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(template + ".txt"), IsBodyHtml = false };
  var htmlMailDefinition = new MailDefinition { BodyFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(template + ".htm"), IsBodyHtml = true };

  MailMessage htmlMessage = htmlMailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(email, replacementDictionary, new Control());
  MailMessage textMessage = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(email, replacementDictionary, new Control());

  AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textMessage.Body, null, "text/plain");
  AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlMessage.Body, null, "text/html");

  var message = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(from) };

  message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
  message.Subject = subject;

  message.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
  message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

  return message;
  }
  ```

Assuming you have your Web.config set up for NetMail, you can call this method from a helper method like so:

```
public bool SendEmail(MailMessage email)
{
    var client = new SmtpClient();

    try
    {
       client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

SendMail(createMailMessage("to@email.com", "from@email.com", "Subject", "~/Path/Template"));
```